# Как правильно добавить запись в БД

Tags: php, yii2

Как правильно добавить запись в БД , если есть две связанные таблицы?
Добавлять по какому то событию? То есть, когда в одной таблице появилась запись только тогда добавляем запись в втрою? При попощи чего это делается?

Интересует вопрос как по yii2 так и по чистому php

И ошибки:

Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чистом PHP это делается вручную - то-есть событий нет. Но для начало тебе необходимо определить какая зависимость между таблицами. Например если первая таблица зависит от второй то вначале добавляешь вторую запись, а потом первую.

Например если ты добавил запись в вторую таблицу то, как правило, как в PDO так и встроенные mysql библиотеки возвращают первичный ключ записи (если конечно ты используешь InnoDB). Если первичный ключ возвращен то это значит запись удачно добавлена смело добавляй зависимую от нее следующею запись.

Если хочешь автоматизировать это на уровне mysql то копай в направлении триггеров mysql. Можешь начать вот [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/) . Но использовать триггеры mysql крайне не рекомендуется поскольку желательно не вносить на уровень баз данных логику!

Comment: Спасибо. Триггеры писал, но мне советывали с ними особо не связываться, во избежания проблем на будущие.. Но я точно пока не наю.

Comment: @gilo1212 Дело в том что триггеры необходимо использовать в том случае если у тебя большой проект и ты можешь себе позволить хотя бы одного разработчика который будет работать только с DB (триггеры, процедуры..) Но если у тебя небольшой проект то очень важно логику приложения централизовать - в целях организованного кода и избежания непредвиденных ошибок. Использовать триггеры заманчиво, но в реальной практике перенос логики в DB усложнит debugging программы и поиск ошибок. Кроме того практика показывает что в конце концов с измененим проекта некоторые триггеры удаляются и реализуются вручную.